# Large 'create' loop operation failing in Heroku Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to move some statistics-related columns out of my Article model and create child classes called Statistics which contains the same info via a `has_many` relationship. However, I have a lot of records that will need creating, and my current method times out after an hour when running in the Rails console via `heroku run rails c`:

```
Article.where("stats_count IS NOT NULL").each do |c|
  s = Statistic.new(
    :dimension => "total_count", 
    :metric => c.stats_count, 
    :article_id => c.id )
  s.save
end
```

In works in dev, but running in production there are about 90,000 Articles which it's trying to loop through and it's failing after creating about 8,500 Statistics.

What would be a best-practice way to execute an operation of this size (I don't mind some downtime, if I know it will work)?

Comment: first, try to replace `each` with `find_each` to work with batches

Comment: how long does it take to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that running you code on a detached one-off dyno would get around the timeout but, in my opinion, you are much better off doing this at the database level.

From a psql console (heroku pg:psql)

```
INSERT INTO statistics (dimension, metric, article_id)
SELECT 'total_count', stats_count, id
FROM articles
WHERE stats_count IS NOT NULL;
```

That will work orders of magnitude faster than the ruby loop.

Comment: This worked - thank you. I've accepted it as an answer as I believe it's the best way to get what I wanted - although the answer from @apneadiving above also did what I needed.